# Uso de funciones de Windows.h para la consola

Tags: c++, consola

Estaba probando las funciones con las que cuenta `Windows.h`. Logré imprimir un mensaje en la consola sin problemas así que quise ir al siguiente paso, leer de ella con `ReadConsoleW` y guardar lo leído en una variable. Pero no sé cómo usarlo bien y me genera el error `0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.`

Mi código consta de la función `ReadError`, que imprime los errores que surjan y esto en la función main:

```
const wchar_t * text = L"Hola";

auto outHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
auto inHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

WCHAR buffer[10];

if (!ReadConsoleW(inHandle, buffer, 10, 0, NULL))
    ReadError();
if (!WriteConsoleW(outHandle, text, 100, 0, NULL))
    ReadError();
```

Busqué en la documentación oficial, en Google y hasta en SO en inglés pero no encontré ningún buen ejemplo conciso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si vamos a la documentacion de `ReadConsoleW`, nos dice sobre el cuarto
parametro:

> lpNumberOfCharsRead [out]
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives the number of characters actually read.

Y si te das cuenta, cuando tu lo llamas:

```
if (!ReadConsoleW(inHandle, buffer, 10, 0, NULL)); // <- Porque tienes un ;?
```

A ese parametro tu le das el valor de `0`. Por eso es que te tira el error de
que esta escribiendo en `0`.

Comment: Era eso. Le pasé la referencia a un DWORD y funcionó perfectamente.